# Mac OS or iOS video player with current subtitle dictionary lookup capabilities

Tags: video, media-player, translation, dictionary, closed-captions

Daum PotPlayer for Windows has this feature - while watching a soft-subtitled video, you can click on any word, and browser page with this word in an online dictionary will open.

I'm looking for something similar either for Mac, or for the iOS. It could be either browser window, or a popup, or just plain "select word(s) on screen with your cursor and copy them to the clipboard".

Comment: Have you found anything for this? I can't find anything. I'm thinking I might make something (simple) for this as a first iOS programming project. If you only need Japanese, you can use [SABUchan](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sabuchan-learn-japanese-from-subtitle/id965622344?mt=8). I want one that lets you use the iOS dictionary lookup easily.